# Spring @CacheEvict using wildcards

Tags: java, spring, caching

Is there any way of using wildcards in @CacheEvict?

I have an application with multi-tenancy that sometimes needs to evict all the data from the cache of the tenant, but not of all tenants in the system.

Consider the following method:

```
@Cacheable(value="users", key="T(Security).getTenant() + #user.key")
public List<User> getUsers(User user) {
    ...
}
```

So, I would like to do something like:

```
@CacheEvict(value="users", key="T(Security).getTenant() + *")
public void deleteOrganization(Organization organization) {
    ...
}
```

Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with 99% of every question in the universe, the answer is: it depends. If your cache manager implements something that deals with that, great. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

If you're using `SimpleCacheManager`, which is a basic in-memory cache manager provided by Spring, you're probably using `ConcurrentMapCache` that also comes with Spring. Although it's not possible to extend `ConcurrentMapCache` to deal with wildcards in keys (because the cache store is private and you can't access it), you could just use it as an inspiration for your own implementation.

Below there's a possible implementation (I didn't really test it much other than to check if it's working). This is a plain copy of `ConcurrentMapCache` with a modification on the `evict()` method. The difference is that this version of `evict()` treats the key to see if it's a regex. In that case, it iterates through all the keys in the store and evict the ones that match the regex.

```
package com.sigraweb.cache;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleValueWrapper;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

public class RegexKeyCache implements Cache {
    private static final Object NULL_HOLDER = new NullHolder();

    private final String name;

    private final ConcurrentMap<Object, Object> store;

    private final boolean allowNullValues;

    public RegexKeyCache(String name) {
        this(name, new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Object>(256), true);
    }

    public RegexKeyCache(String name, boolean allowNullValues) {
        this(name, new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Object>(256), allowNullValues);
    }

    public RegexKeyCache(String name, ConcurrentMap<Object, Object> store, boolean allowNullValues) {
        Assert.notNull(name, "Name must not be null");
        Assert.notNull(store, "Store must not be null");
        this.name = name;
        this.store = store;
        this.allowNullValues = allowNullValues;
    }

    @Override
    public final String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public final ConcurrentMap<Object, Object> getNativeCache() {
        return this.store;
    }

    public final boolean isAllowNullValues() {
        return this.allowNullValues;
    }

    @Override
    public ValueWrapper get(Object key) {
        Object value = this.store.get(key);
        return toWrapper(value);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T get(Object key, Class<T> type) {
        Object value = fromStoreValue(this.store.get(key));
        if (value != null && type != null && !type.isInstance(value)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cached value is not of required type [" + type.getName() + "]: " + value);
        }
        return (T) value;
    }

    @Override
    public void put(Object key, Object value) {
        this.store.put(key, toStoreValue(value));
    }

    @Override
    public ValueWrapper putIfAbsent(Object key, Object value) {
        Object existing = this.store.putIfAbsent(key, value);
        return toWrapper(existing);
    }

    @Override
    public void evict(Object key) {
        this.store.remove(key);
        if (key.toString().startsWith("regex:")) {
            String r = key.toString().replace("regex:", "");
            for (Object k : this.store.keySet()) {
                if (k.toString().matches(r)) {
                    this.store.remove(k);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        this.store.clear();
    }

    protected Object fromStoreValue(Object storeValue) {
        if (this.allowNullValues && storeValue == NULL_HOLDER) {
            return null;
        }
        return storeValue;
    }

    protected Object toStoreValue(Object userValue) {
        if (this.allowNullValues && userValue == null) {
            return NULL_HOLDER;
        }
        return userValue;
    }

    private ValueWrapper toWrapper(Object value) {
        return (value != null ? new SimpleValueWrapper(fromStoreValue(value)) : null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class NullHolder implements Serializable {
    }
}
```

I trust that readers know how to initialize the cache manager with a custom cache implementation. There's lots of documentation out there that shows you how to do that. After your project is properly configured, you can use the annotation normally like so:

```
@CacheEvict(value = { "cacheName" }, key = "'regex:#tenant'+'.*'")
public myMethod(String tenant){
...
}
```

Again, this is far from being properly tested, but it gives you a way to do what you want. If you're using another cache manager, you could extends its cache implementation similarly.

Answer (score 9):

Answer is: No.

And it is no easy way to achieve what you want.

1. Spring Cache annotations must be simple to be easy to implement by cache provider.
2. Efficient caching must be simple. There is a key and value. If key is found in cache use the value, otherwise compute value and put to cache. Efficient key must have fast and honest **equals()** and **hashcode()**. Assume you cached many pairs (key,value) from one tenant. For efficiency different keys should have different **hashcode()**. And you decide to evict whole tenant. It is no easy to find tenant elements in cache. You have to iterate all cached pairs and discard pairs belonging to the tenant. It is not efficient. It is rather not atomic, so it is complicated and needs some synchronization. Synchronization is not efficient.

Therefore no.

But, if you find a solution tell me, because feature you want is really useful.

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me on Redis Cache.
Suppose you want to delete all Cache entries with key prefix: 'cache-name:object-name:parentKey'. Call method with key value `cache-name:object-name:parentKey*`.

```
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations;    
...
private final RedisOperations<Object, Object> redisTemplate;
...    
public void evict(Object key)
{
    redisTemplate.delete(redisTemplate.keys(key));
}
```

From RedisOperations.java

```
/**
 * Delete given {@code keys}.
 *
 * @param keys must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return The number of keys that were removed.
 * @see <a href="http://redis.io/commands/del">Redis Documentation: DEL</a>
 */
void delete(Collection<K> keys);

/**
 * Find all keys matching the given {@code pattern}.
 *
 * @param pattern must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return
 * @see <a href="http://redis.io/commands/keys">Redis Documentation: KEYS</a>
 */
Set<K> keys(K pattern);
```

Comment: note that the keys command is not recommended for production use. " This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. " https://redis.io/commands/keys

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue as well. I solved it that way.

**My Config Class**

```
@Bean
RedisTemplate redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate template = new RedisTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setValueSerializer(new RedisSerializerGzip());
    return template;
}
```

**My Util Class**

```
public class CacheService {

    final RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    public void evictCachesByPrefix(String prefix) {
        Set<String> keys = redisTemplate.keys(prefix + "*");
        for (String key : keys) {
            redisTemplate.delete(key);
        }
    }
}
```

> Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in
> production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance
> when it is executed against large databases.
> https://redis.io/commands/keys

Answer (score 1):

Include the tenant as part of the cache name, by implementing a custom CacheResolver; extending and implementing `SimpleCacheResolver.getCacheName`

then do evict all keys

`@CacheEvict(value = {CacheName.CACHE1, CacheName.CACHE2}, allEntries = true)`

But note that if you are using redis as your backing cache, then under the hood spring uses the KEYS command, so the solution will not scale. Once you get few 100K keys in redis, KEYS will take 150ms and the redis server will bottleneck on CPU. Naughty spring.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to remove all stored orders from cache and i complited it this way.

```
@CacheEvict(value = "List<Order>", allEntries = true)
```

As i understand this way will be removed all lists stored with this value. So you can create another structure and it also can be a kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by leaving the AOP-Pattern in this special case.

read remains annotation-driven:

```
    @Cacheable(value = "imageCache", keyGenerator = "imageKeyGenerator", unless="#result == null")
public byte[] getImageData(int objectId, int imageType, int width, int height, boolean sizeAbsolute) { 
// ... 
}


public boolean deleteImage(int objId, int type) {
    removeFromCacheByPrefix("imageCache", ImageCacheKeyGenerator.generateKey(objId, type));
    int rc = jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_DELETE_IMAGE, new Object[] {objId,type});
    return rc > 0;
}
```

as you can see, the deleteImage(...) has no annotation, but calls removeFromCacheByPrefix(...).
this is a function in the superclass of the repository which looks like this:

```
protected void removeFromCacheByPrefix(String cacheName, String prefix) {
    var cache = this.cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>();
    cache.forEach(entry -> {
        var key = String.valueOf(entry.getKey());
        if (key.startsWith(prefix)) {
            keys.add(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()));
        }
    });
    cache.removeAll(keys);
}
```

works fine for me this way!