# How to use regex in SpEL while evicting specific keys which match the regex in key attribute of @CacheEvict

Tags: spring, spring-cache

I want to evict all keys starting with a certain string for a given cache
For eg:

```
@CacheEvict(cacheNames="LOCATION", key="#p0*")
public void evictLocation(String location, String type ) {
    //some code here
}
```

I want to evict all cached objects who have keys starting with location passed in argument.
I tried with * quantifier, but it did not work

Comment: were you able to achieve it?

Comment: Please refer to this question also [Spring @CacheEvict using wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749049/spring-cacheevict-using-wildcards)

Comment: I shared a similar solution under another post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69899617/7927573

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regrex in the SpEL expression, please try add `#{}` in your key value, ---

```
@CacheEvict(cacheNames="LOCATION", key="#{yourLocationArg*}")
public void evictLocation(String location, String type ) {
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work
I tried the below way
@CacheEvict(cacheNames="LOCATION", key="#{p0*}")
But eviction did not take place

Comment: please more detail

Comment: @Liping Huang is this really work? can you share more code ?

Comment: It is not working