# Spring @Cacheable evict by SPEL or String pattern Key

Tags: spring, caching

I'm caching a Pageable result:

```
  @Cacheable(value="TasksByCategory", key = "{#categoryId, #pageable.offset, #pageable.pageSize}")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<Task> getTasksByCategory(UUID categoryId, Pageable pageable){
        return taskRepository.findByCategoryId(categoryId, pageable);
    }
```

And I want to evict the Cache when a new Entry is added in the way smth like (I don't to evict all the cache entries):

```
    @CacheEvict(value="TasksByCategory", key = "{#task.categoryId** }")
    @Transactional
    public Task createTask(Task task){
        return taskRepository.save(task);
    }
```

But I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: That is not how the cache works. It caches the method result not the individual entities. If you are using JPA, don't use `@Cacheable` insetad configure the 2nd level caching of your JPA provider to have caching of entities and automatic management of evicting them/updating them etc.

Comment: Off course it caches the result, in my example I have different keys (different categories) and I don't want to evict all keys, but only certain key (category with certain Pageable)

Comment: THen don't use a different key... That simply won't work as adding a task (or whatever) will change the offset etc. so it all seems flawed from the start.

Comment: @M.Deinum NEVER is a strong word :)

Jeorge Moore you can check this example as a reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40680741/17578923

Comment: Which wouldn't be needed if you would properly configure the 2nd level cache/query cache of your JPA provider. Which was my initial comment (generally `@Cacheble` and JPA are something you shouldn't combine, but hey please don't listen to me, eventually I get hired to solve the issues it creates).

Comment: L2Cache is good in some cases, and bad in others, for example, it can easily lead to an N+1 query, for example:
https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-query-cache-n-plus-1-issue/
 so claiming that L2Cache is always good is not too wise, as well as blaming people when you don't know the whole situation.